# Cannot find module './App.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, svelte

I have a setup that integrates electron with svelte along with typescript support.

when I run the `rollup` script to compile svelte app, i am getting cannot find module `./App.svelte` error as shown below.

```
Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module './App.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Here's my `package.json` configuration :

```
{
  "name": "tapwire-electron-first",
  "productName": "tapwire-electron-first",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron-start": "tsc && electron-forge start",
    "electron-package": "electron-forge package",
    "electron-make": "electron-forge make",
    "electron-publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "electron-lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "svelte-build": "rollup -c",
    "svelte-dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "svelte-start": "sirv public",
    "svelte-validate": "svelte-check",
    "start": "run-p svelte-dev electron-start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "nateshmbhat",
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "tapwire_electron_first"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.53",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.53",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.53",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.53",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.53",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "electron": "10.1.3",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^2.28.2",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^6.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "svelte": "^3.29.0",
    "svelte-check": "^1.0.55",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a well tested starter pack for electron and svelte : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/svelte-electron-ts-starter

Comment: See [official docs on Svelte with TypeScript](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Turns out i had to install `@tsconfig/svelte` as a dev dependency first then extend this with my `tsconfig.json` as shown below :

#### Install @tsconfig/svelte

```
npm i --save-dev @tsconfig/svelte
```

#### Add this tsconfig as the base config file in your `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The culprit on my end was a stale `global.d.ts`. I had `/// <reference types="@sveltejs/kit" />` set, but was trying to change the project to vanilla Svelte. Fixing it to have `/// <reference types="svelte" />` instead did the trick.

Comment: in my case, this file was missing altogether

Comment: If you're using Vite, you may have to change the setting in `vite-end.d.ts`.

Comment: Yeah, for me this line was just missing. They tell you to add it in https://github.com/tsconfig/bases#svelte-tsconfigjson

Answer (score 8):

If [Natesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64194572) doesn't work for you, this file should work as a basic shim:

```
// svelte-shim.d.ts

declare module "*.svelte" {
    import type { ComponentType } from "svelte";
    const component: ComponentType;
    export default component;
}
```

This essentially tells TypeScript that any .svelte files it doesn't otherwise know what to do with should be read in as Svelte components. You won't get any of their exported props or methods, but if all you need is to use their basic `ComponentType` interface, this should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a default `react-ts` vite project when compiling Typescript with `tsc`

I had to remove following line in `tsconfig.json`

```
"skipLibCheck": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the initial JS setup for Svelte installed; what worked for me is going into my jsconfig.json file and setting `compilerOptions.checkJS` to false, which in the config itself the comment described this option as:

> Typecheck JS in `.svelte` and `.js` files by default...

-- EDIT
I'll leave this posted here, but I realized the original question had a TS setup after the fact. The responses in this thread did lead me to discover this compiler option, though.