# Cannot find module './SLink.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, jestjs, svelte

I'm trying to configure Jest with Svelte and TypeScript in an existing project.

I've setup everything as per [this article](https://daveceddia.com/svelte-typescript-jest/) (using Babel and [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/)).

When I run the test I get this:

```sh
FAIL src/tests/methods.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/router/components/index.ts:1:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './SLink.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations.

    1 import SLink from './SLink.svelte';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.705 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I have other components being imported that don't throw this error, the only difference being that `SLink` is imported into a regular `.ts` file while my other components are imported into other components (with the exception of `App.svelte`).

If I change the export to an empty string, it goes through the test as it should (though, it still throws an error that this component can't be rendered).

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194571/cannot-find-module-app-svelte-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations) suggests adding `@tsconfig/svelte`, which I've already done.

If I add `// @ts-ignore` above the import, it works exactly as it should, but, is there another way around this?

---

## Relevant code:

**src/tests/methods.test.ts:**

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import App from '../App.svelte';

test('should render', () => {
    const results = render(App);

    expect(() => results.getByText('Hello world!')).not.toThrow();
});
```

**src/router/components/index.ts:**

```
import SLink from './SLink.svelte';

export { SLink };
```

`SLink` is an ordinary Svelte component that **doesn't** use TypeScript.

**jest.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    clearMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.svelte$': [
            'svelte-jester',
            {
                preprocess: true,
            },
        ],
        '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'svelte'],
};
```

**babel.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
};
```

**svelte.config.js:**

```
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

module.exports = {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
};
```

**File tree:**

```
src
|_ tests
  |_ methods.test.ts
|_ router
  |_ components
    |_ index.ts
    |_ SLink.svelte
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was seeing a similar error, and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582171/3604254) to a different question, I realized I had accidentally stopped referencing the Svelte types due to an override in my tsconfig.json file.

My tsconfig extended the Svelte defaults, but I had added the `compilerOptions` override below:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  }
}
```

On building my project, I was getting this error (similarly, regarding an import of a Svelte component in a `.ts` file):

```
(!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module './App.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

It seems that I was accidentally overriding some of the Svelte defaults. Per the suggestion linked to above, I amended my tsconfig like so (adding `"svelte"` to the types array):

```json
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "svelte", "jest"]
  }
}
```

In my case, this fixed the error.